# javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: protocol_version with Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, ssl

Receive this error running selenium script

> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: protocol_version

Stack trace below:

> Driver info: driver.version: HtmlUnitDriver
>       at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:208)
>       at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:154)
>       at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:1979)
>       at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1086)
>       at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1332)
>       at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1359)
>       at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1343)
>       at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:394)
>       at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:353)
>       at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.httpclient.HtmlUnitSSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(HtmlUnitSSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:189)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:134)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:353)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:380)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:88)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:71)
>       at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.HttpWebConnection.getResponse(HttpWebConnection.java:179)
>       at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponseFromWebConnection(WebClient.java:1321)
>       at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponse(WebClient.java:1238)
>       at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:346)
>       at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:415)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.get(HtmlUnitDriver.java:541)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.get(HtmlUnitDriver.java:530)
>       at com.mimos.performance.PerfTest.PerfTest(PerfTest.java:34)

Build info: version: '2.48.2', revision: '41bccdd10cf2c0560f637404c2d96164b67d9d67', time: '2015-10-09 13:08:06'

java version "1.7.0_79"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_79-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.79-b02, mixed mode)

```
    HtmlUnitDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();        
    driver.get(url);
    WebElement passwordLogo = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/ul/li/a"));
    passwordLogo.click();
    WebElement userID = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/form[1]/input[1]"));
    userID.sendKeys(username);
    WebElement next = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/form[1]/input[2]"));
    next.click();
    WebElement password =  driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/form[1]/div/input[1]"));
    password.sendKeys(password);
    WebElement login = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/form[1]/div/input[3]"));
    login.click();
    System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
```

Answer (score 0):

Good morning. Possibly related to  [[javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: protocol_version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16541627/javax-net-ssl-sslexception-received-fatal-alert-protocol-version)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16541627/javax-net-ssl-sslexception-received-fatal-alert-protocol-version)

> This seems like a protocol version mismatch, this exception normally happens when there is a mismatch between SSL protocol version used by the client and the server. your clients should use a proctocol version supported by the server.

Comment: No sure how or why, manage to overcome the issue by upgrading my jdk to 8