# javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No appropriate protocol

Tags: ssl, java-8, tomcat8

i have install tomcat 8(ssl support) with java 1.8.
When start tomcat catalina out write

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.activate(Handshaker.java:503)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.kickstartHandshake(SSLEngineImpl.java:729)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.beginHandshake(SSLEngineImpl.java:756)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SecureNioChannel.reset(SecureNioChannel.java:94)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SecureNioChannel.<init>(SecureNioChannel.java:76)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.setSocketOptions(NioEndpoint.java:544)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$Acceptor.run(NioEndpoint.java:697)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

and this

```
12-Dec-2016 14:12:37.297 WARNING [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.getEnableableProtocols None of the SSL protocols specified are supported by the SSL engine : [TLSv1+TLSv1.1+TLSv1.2]
```

With old version of tomcat and java errors don't occur.

My server.xml configuration

```
    <Connector port="443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
               maxThreads="700" scheme="https" secure="true"
               clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" sslEnabledProtocols="TLSv1+TLSv1.1+TLSv1.2"
keystoreFile="/var/lib/tomcat8/keystore" keystorePass="********" keystoreType="JKS"
keyAlias="tomcat"
ciphers="TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,
TLS_RSA_EXPORT1024_WITH_RC4_56_MD5,
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256,
TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5,
TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA,
TLS_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA,
TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA,
TLS_RSA_EXPORT1024_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA"
/>
```

What could be the problem?
Thanks

Comment: `TLSv1+TLSv1.1+TLSv1.2` should be `TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2`. Is it a typo? If it is, probably the cipher suite you have set has no correspondence in server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [Apache Tomcat 8 Configuration Reference](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/http.html), `sslEnabledProtocols` should represent

> The comma separated list of SSL protocols to support for HTTPS connections.

The [Apache Tomcat 8 - Security Considerations](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/security-howto.html) document has an example indicating the correct usage of this parameter --
`sslEnabledProtocols="TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2"`. You have this incorrectly specified to use `+` instead of `,` -- `TLSv1+TLSv1.1+TLSv1.2`.