# Soap ui SSl error ERROR:javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: protocol_version

Tags: ssl, soapui, tls1.2

I am seeing below error when I hit a service over https. I've tried changing TLS version in Soap ui VM options file as below:

-Dsoapui.https.protocols=TLSv1.0
-Dsoapui.https.protocols=TLSv1.2

and no luck. Please advise

```
    Thu Sep 07 11:32:47 BST 2017:ERROR:javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: protocol_version
   javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: protocol_version
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionOutputBuffer.flushBuffer(AbstractSessionOutputBuffer.java:131)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionOutputBuffer.flush(AbstractSessionOutputBuffer.java:138)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.LoggingSessionOutputBuffer.flush(LoggingSessionOutputBuffer.java:95)
    at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.doFlush(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:270)
    at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.flush(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:275)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractClientConnAdapter.flush(AbstractClientConnAdapter.java:197)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doSendRequest(HttpRequestExecutor.java:258)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.http.HttpClientSupport$SoapUIHttpRequestExecutor.doSendRequest(HttpClientSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:123)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryExecute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:633)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:454)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:820)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:754)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.http.HttpClientSupport$Helper.execute(HttpClientSupport.java:233)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.http.HttpClientSupport.execute(HttpClientSupport.java:323)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.submit.transports.http.HttpClientRequestTransport.submitRequest(HttpClientRequestTransport.java:297)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.submit.transports.http.HttpClientRequestTransport.sendRequest(HttpClientRequestTransport.java:227)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.WsdlSubmit.run(WsdlSubmit.java:119)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Note: SoapUI version is 5.3.0 and Java version is

Comment: Try to use one version. either `1.0`, or `1.1` or `1.2` but not together.

Comment: @Rao yes, I've been trying one at a time.. but no luck..

Comment: @Nareshsadu Did you manage to find a solution to this problem? I am seeing the same problem using the same version.

Answer (score 12):

Please add **-Dsoapui.https.protocols=SSLv3,TLSv1.2** to SoapUI-5.3.0.vmoptions file and it should solve the issue.

Comment: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate) - Getting this error after adding above lines

Answer (score 4):

For those still unable to get SoapUI to work after altering your vmoptions file, here is the next thing to [try](https://siking.wordpress.com/2016/02/18/another-way-to-fix-sslhandshakeexception-in-soapui/).

Accourding to SiKing, the issue is with the provided version of Java bundled with SoapUI. SoapUI is smart enough to look for a local version if it can't find its own, so simply renaming the jre folder solves the problem.

1. Go to your SoapUI installation folder
2. Rename the `jre` folder `jre.ignore`
3. Restart SoapUI.

This solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

> Fix SSL error when you run SOAP UI

I have faced the same issue with the following error `javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: protocol_version` in **SoapUI**. But resolved by adding [`https.protocols`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#InstallationAndCustomization) system property in the file **`SoapUI-5.3.0.vmoptions`**

[image]

- Open the file using Notepad.
- Add this protocol at the bottom “`-Dsoapui.https.protocols=SSLv3,TLSv1.2`” and save the changes.
- Close SOAP UI and relaunch. It works with no SSL error when you make API call. (Perform test ping call to check).

> Add (-Dsoapui.https.protocols=SSLv3,TLSv1.2) in the VMOPTIONS file under the Bin folder. Eg:`C:\Softwares\SoapUI-5.3.0\bin\SoapUI-5.3.0.vmoptions`

```
-XX:MinHeapFreeRatio=20
-XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=40
-Xms128m
-Xmx1000m
-Dsoapui.properties=soapui.properties
-Dsoapui.home=C:\Softwares\SoapUI-5.3.0/bin
-Dsoapui.ext.libraries=C:\Softwares\SoapUI-5.3.0/bin/ext
-Dsoapui.ext.listeners=C:\Softwares\SoapUI-5.3.0/bin/listeners
-Dsoapui.ext.actions=C:\Softwares\SoapUI-5.3.0/bin/actions
-Dwsi.dir=C:\Softwares\SoapUI-5.3.0/wsi-test-tools
-Djava.library.path=C:\Softwares\SoapUI-5.3.0/bin
-Djava.util.Arrays.useLegacyMergeSort=true
-splash:SoapUI-Spashscreen.png
-Dsoapui.https.protocols=SSLv3,TLSv1.2
```

Full error Log:

```log
Mon Sep 14 07:47:30 CEST 2020:DEBUG:I/O error closing connection
   javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection has been shutdown: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: protocol_version
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.checkEOF(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.checkWrite(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionOutputBuffer.flushBuffer(AbstractSessionOutputBuffer.java:131)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionOutputBuffer.flush(AbstractSessionOutputBuffer.java:138)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.LoggingSessionOutputBuffer.flush(LoggingSessionOutputBuffer.java:95)
    at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.doFlush(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:270)
    at org.apache.http.impl.SocketHttpClientConnection.close(SocketHttpClientConnection.java:245)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.close(DefaultClientConnection.java:164)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.close(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:152)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.closeConnection(HttpRequestExecutor.java:142)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:129)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryExecute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:633)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:454)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:820)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:754)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.http.HttpClientSupport$Helper.execute(HttpClientSupport.java:233)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.http.HttpClientSupport.execute(HttpClientSupport.java:323)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.submit.transports.http.HttpClientRequestTransport.submitRequest(HttpClientRequestTransport.java:297)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.submit.transports.http.HttpClientRequestTransport.sendRequest(HttpClientRequestTransport.java:227)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.WsdlSubmit.run(WsdlSubmit.java:119)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
   Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: protocol_version
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionOutputBuffer.flushBuffer(AbstractSessionOutputBuffer.java:131)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionOutputBuffer.write(AbstractSessionOutputBuffer.java:151)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.LoggingSessionOutputBuffer.write(LoggingSessionOutputBuffer.java:74)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.ContentLengthOutputStream.write(ContentLengthOutputStream.java:114)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.ContentLengthOutputStream.write(ContentLengthOutputStream.java:120)
    at org.apache.http.entity.ByteArrayEntity.writeTo(ByteArrayEntity.java:68)
    at org.apache.http.entity.HttpEntityWrapper.writeTo(HttpEntityWrapper.java:96)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.EntityEnclosingRequestWrapper$EntityWrapper.writeTo(EntityEnclosingRequestWrapper.java:108)
    at org.apache.http.impl.entity.EntitySerializer.serialize(EntitySerializer.java:120)
    at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.sendRequestEntity(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:263)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractClientConnAdapter.sendRequestEntity(AbstractClientConnAdapter.java:227)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doSendRequest(HttpRequestExecutor.java:255)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.http.HttpClientSupport$SoapUIHttpRequestExecutor.doSendRequest(HttpClientSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:123)
    ... 14 more
Mon Sep 14 07:47:30 CEST 2020:DEBUG:Closing the connection.
Mon Sep 14 07:47:30 CEST 2020:DEBUG:Connection closed
Mon Sep 14 07:47:30 CEST 2020:DEBUG:Connection shut down
Mon Sep 14 07:47:30 CEST 2020:ERROR:Exception in request: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: protocol_version
Mon Sep 14 07:47:30 CEST 2020:ERROR:An error occurred [Received fatal alert: protocol_version], see error log for details
Mon Sep 14 07:47:30 CEST 2020:INFO:Error getting response for [ScheduleSoap11.SendScheduleMessage:Request 1]; javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: protocol_version
```

---

@See

- [Java: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: protocol_version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49556107/5081877)
- [Apache Tomcat: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No appropriate protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41102353/5081877)
  8 [How to fix SSL error when you run SOAP UI | Adobe Sign](https://helpx.adobe.com/sign/kb/how-to-fix-ssl-error-when-you-run-soap-ui-adobe-sign.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can configure supported versions of SSL in your SoapUI-5.3.1.vmoptions file, by adding a line e.g.:

-Dsoapui.https.protocols=SSLv3,TLSv1.2