# Jmeter 3.1- javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: protocol_version

Tags: ssl, jmeter, ssl-certificate, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins

We are trying to run https request in  Jmeter 3.1.

[image]
But while executing getting following error.

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: protocol_version
at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(Unknown Source)
at  org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.flushRequestOutputStream(HttpConnection.java:828)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.writeRequest(HttpMethodBase.java:2116)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.execute(HttpMethodBase.java:1096)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:398)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:323)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC3Impl.sample(HTTPHC3Impl.java:269)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:74)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1166)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1155)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:475)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:418)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:249)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

We tried following solutions but did't solved the issue:

1. added "https.default.protocol=TLSv1" in "jmeter.properties" file
2. Tried solution provided in
   http://rajanmanoj.blogspot.in/2011/02/how-to-test-ssl-using-jmeter.html
   this link

We are Using Jmeter 3.1, Java Jdk 1.7, Windows 7

Answer (score 1):

Https default protocol may vary depending on the version of JVM.
You can change it. Go to jmeter home directory. Open jmeter.properties file. Uncomment line:

```
https.default.protocol=SSLv3
```

May be you need to restart jmeter after change. Not sure about that.

Answer (score 0):

This is highly due to protocol version mismatch. There is mismatch between SSL protocol version used by the client and the server.

Make sure that you have latest version of Java and JMeter installed in your system. Also check for the security certificate in `JMETER_HOME\bin` folder.

You can check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16541627/javax-net-ssl-sslexception-received-fatal-alert-protocol-version) for more details.