# "cannot open git-upload-pack" - Cloning project in Eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse, github, egit

I'm making a clone of my project that is in Github in the Eclipse IDE.
After entering all the access data, the following error occurs:

> https://github.com/"COMPANY NAME"/"PROJECTNAME".git: cannot open git-upload-pack

I already added the **http.sslVerify = false** - did not work

I configured the **RSA key** - did not work either

I use: Windows 10 / Java 7 / Eclipse Luna Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2)

More details of the error

```
org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.TransportException: 
https://github.com/"COMPANYNAME"/"PROJECTNAME".git: cannot open git-upload-pack
at org.eclipse.jgit.api.LsRemoteCommand.call(LsRemoteCommand.java:196)
at 
org.eclipse.egit.core.op.ListRemoteOperation.run(ListRemoteOperation.java:99)
at org.eclipse.egit.ui.internal.clone.SourceBranchPage$8.run(SourceBranchPage.java:324)
at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:122)
Caused by: org.eclipse.jgit.errors.TransportException: https://github.com/"COMPANYNAME"/"PROJECTNAME".git: cannot open git-upload-pack
at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportHttp.connect(TransportHttp.java:521)
at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportHttp.openFetch(TransportHttp.java:309)
at org.eclipse.jgit.api.LsRemoteCommand.call(LsRemoteCommand.java:175)
... 3 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: protocol_version
at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.http.JDKHttpConnection.getResponseCode(JDKHttpConnection.java:98)
at org.eclipse.jgit.util.HttpSupport.response(HttpSupport.java:168)
at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportHttp.connect(TransportHttp.java:475)
... 5 more
```

Session Data:

```
eclipse.buildId=4.4.2.M20150204-1700
java.version=1.7.0_79
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=pt_BR
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product 
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16541627/javax-net-ssl-sslexception-received-fatal-alert-protocol-version . Use a newer JRE.

Comment: I believe that it is not my case, I had already seen this page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/138819) to a related question on Salesforce Stack Exchange. It worked for me.

To elaborate, GitHub recently (as of February 8, 2018) removed support for a number of outdated cryptographic standards. See [this announcement](https://githubengineering.com/crypto-removal-notice/) for more details on that.

Unfortunately, this list includes TLSv1, which is the default TLS implementation used by Java 7. I encountered the same problem since I was interfacing with GitHub via EGit on a fairly ancient Eclipse build still using Java 7, and sure enough, it was explicitly set to use TLS1.0. I followed the recommended steps to force my Java to use TLS1.1 and 1.2, and the problem was magically solved.

Comment: didn't help. I am using Eclipse 2019-12 and Java 11.

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse 2019-12 has an issue running on **IBM JDK** that implements

```
SSLContext.getInstance("TLS")
```

differently than the other JDKs like Oracle JDK or OpenJDK.

The issue is explained in this [**Eclipse forum post**](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1101861/)

To resolve the issue you need to set a runtime parameter:

```
-Dcom.ibm.jsse2.overrideDefaultTLS=true
```

in the **eclipse.ini** file.

also, if still not working, you need to add one of the following parameters:

```
-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2
-Djdk.tls.client.protocols=TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2
```

Some people observed that in some contexts the order of the items do count, so

```
-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2,TLSv1.1
```

is not the same with

```
-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2
```

The last in the list tend to have priority in front of the others.

Other official articles from IBM explaining the "functionality" are the following:

[**IBM Article 1**](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/how-configure-force-controller-use-tls-12)

[**IBM Article 2**](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSYKE2_8.0.0/com.ibm.java.security.component.80.doc/security-component/jsse2Docs/matchsslcontext_tls.html)

[**IBM Article 3**](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/how-do-i-change-default-ssl-protocol-my-java-client-application-will-use)