# Failed to launch spark-shell with spark-cassandra-connector find the log

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

```
$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-shell --packages datastax:spark-cassandra-connector:2.0.0-M2-s_2.11 --conf spark.cassandra.connection.host=127.0.0.1
Ivy Default Cache set to: /home/gopalkrishna/.ivy2/cache
The jars for the packages stored in: /home/gopalkrishna/.ivy2/jars
:: loading settings :: url = jar:file:/home/gopalkrishna/INSTALL/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.6/jars/ivy-2.4.0.jar!/org/apache/ivy/core/settings/ivysettings.xml
datastax#spark-cassandra-connector added as a dependency
:: resolving dependencies :: org.apache.spark#spark-submit-parent;1.0
    confs: [default]
    found datastax#spark-cassandra-connector;2.0.0-M2-s_2.11 in spark-packages
downloading http://dl.bintray.com/spark-packages/maven/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/2.0.0-M2-s_2.11/spark-cassandra-connector-2.0.0-M2-s_2.11.jar ...
    [SUCCESSFUL ] datastax#spark-cassandra-connector;2.0.0-M2-s_2.11!spark-cassandra-connector.jar (7998ms)
:: resolution report :: resolve 33340ms :: artifacts dl 8002ms
    :: modules in use:
    datastax#spark-cassandra-connector;2.0.0-M2-s_2.11 from spark-packages in [default]
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    |                  |            modules            ||   artifacts   |
    |       conf       | number| search|dwnlded|evicted|| number|dwnlded|
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    |      default     |   7   |   1   |   1   |   0   ||   1   |   1   |
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------

:: problems summary ::
:::: WARNINGS
        module not found: commons-beanutils#commons-beanutils;1.8.0

    ==== local-m2-cache: tried

      file:/home/gopalkrishna/.m2/repository/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils/1.8.0/commons-beanutils-1.8.0.pom

      -- artifact commons-beanutils#commons-beanutils;1.8.0!commons-beanutils.jar:

      file:/home/gopalkrishna/.m2/repository/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils/1.8.0/commons-beanutils-1.8.0.jar

    ==== local-ivy-cache: tried

      /home/gopalkrishna/.ivy2/local/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils/1.8.0/ivys/ivy.xml

      -- artifact commons-beanutils#commons-beanutils;1.8.0!commons-beanutils.jar:

      /home/gopalkrishna/.ivy2/local/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils/1.8.0/jars/commons-beanutils.jar

    ==== central: tried

      https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils/1.8.0/commons-beanutils-1.8.0.pom

      -- artifact commons-beanutils#commons-beanutils;1.8.0!commons-beanutils.jar:

      https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils/1.8.0/commons-beanutils-1.8.0.jar

    ==== spark-packages: tried

      http://dl.bintray.com/spark-packages/maven/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils/1.8.0/commons-beanutils-1.8.0.pom

      -- artifact commons-beanutils#commons-beanutils;1.8.0!commons-beanutils.jar:

      http://dl.bintray.com/spark-packages/maven/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils/1.8.0/commons-beanutils-1.8.0.jar

        module not found: org.joda#joda-convert;1.2

    ==== local-m2-cache: tried

      file:/home/gopalkrishna/.m2/repository/org/joda/joda-convert/1.2/joda-convert-1.2.pom

      -- artifact org.joda#joda-convert;1.2!joda-convert.jar:

      file:/home/gopalkrishna/.m2/repository/org/joda/joda-convert/1.2/joda-convert-1.2.jar

    ==== local-ivy-cache: tried

      /home/gopalkrishna/.ivy2/local/org.joda/joda-convert/1.2/ivys/ivy.xml

      -- artifact org.joda#joda-convert;1.2!joda-convert.jar:

      /home/gopalkrishna/.ivy2/local/org.joda/joda-convert/1.2/jars/joda-convert.jar

    ==== central: tried

      https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/joda/joda-convert/1.2/joda-convert-1.2.pom

      -- artifact org.joda#joda-convert;1.2!joda-convert.jar:

      https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/joda/joda-convert/1.2/joda-convert-1.2.jar

    ==== spark-packages: tried

      http://dl.bintray.com/spark-packages/maven/org/joda/joda-convert/1.2/joda-convert-1.2.pom

      -- artifact org.joda#joda-convert;1.2!joda-convert.jar:

      http://dl.bintray.com/spark-packages/maven/org/joda/joda-convert/1.2/joda-convert-1.2.jar

        module not found: joda-time#joda-time;2.3

    ==== local-m2-cache: tried

      file:/home/gopalkrishna/.m2/repository/joda-time/joda-time/2.3/joda-time-2.3.pom

      -- artifact joda-time#joda-time;2.3!joda-time.jar:

      file:/home/gopalkrishna/.m2/repository/joda-time/joda-time/2.3/joda-time-2.3.jar

    ==== local-ivy-cache: tried

      /home/gopalkrishna/.ivy2/local/joda-time/joda-time/2.3/ivys/ivy.xml

      -- artifact joda-time#joda-time;2.3!joda-time.jar:

      /home/gopalkrishna/.ivy2/local/joda-time/joda-time/2.3/jars/joda-time.jar

    ==== central: tried

      https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/joda-time/joda-time/2.3/joda-time-2.3.pom

      -- artifact joda-time#joda-time;2.3!joda-time.jar:

      https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/joda-time/joda-time/2.3/joda-time-2.3.jar

    ==== spark-packages: tried

      http://dl.bintray.com/spark-packages/maven/joda-time/joda-time/2.3/joda-time-2.3.pom

      -- artifact joda-time#joda-time;2.3!joda-time.jar:

      http://dl.bintray.com/spark-packages/maven/joda-time/joda-time/2.3/joda-time-2.3.jar

        module not found: io.netty#netty-all;4.0.33.Final

    ==== local-m2-cache: tried

      file:/home/gopalkrishna/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-all/4.0.33.Final/netty-all-4.0.33.Final.pom

      -- artifact io.netty#netty-all;4.0.33.Final!netty-all.jar:

      file:/home/gopalkrishna/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-all/4.0.33.Final/netty-all-4.0.33.Final.jar

    ==== local-ivy-cache: tried

      /home/gopalkrishna/.ivy2/local/io.netty/netty-all/4.0.33.Final/ivys/ivy.xml

      -- artifact io.netty#netty-all;4.0.33.Final!netty-all.jar:

      /home/gopalkrishna/.ivy2/local/io.netty/netty-all/4.0.33.Final/jars/netty-all.jar

    ==== central: tried

      https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/netty/netty-all/4.0.33.Final/netty-all-4.0.33.Final.pom

      -- artifact io.netty#netty-all;4.0.33.Final!netty-all.jar:

      https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/netty/netty-all/4.0.33.Final/netty-all-4.0.33.Final.jar

    ==== spark-packages: tried

      http://dl.bintray.com/spark-packages/maven/io/netty/netty-all/4.0.33.Final/netty-all-4.0.33.Final.pom

      -- artifact io.netty#netty-all;4.0.33.Final!netty-all.jar:

      http://dl.bintray.com/spark-packages/maven/io/netty/netty-all/4.0.33.Final/netty-all-4.0.33.Final.jar

        module not found: com.twitter#jsr166e;1.1.0

    ==== local-m2-cache: tried

      file:/home/gopalkrishna/.m2/repository/com/twitter/jsr166e/1.1.0/jsr166e-1.1.0.pom

      -- artifact com.twitter#jsr166e;1.1.0!jsr166e.jar:

      file:/home/gopalkrishna/.m2/repository/com/twitter/jsr166e/1.1.0/jsr166e-1.1.0.jar

    ==== local-ivy-cache: tried

      /home/gopalkrishna/.ivy2/local/com.twitter/jsr166e/1.1.0/ivys/ivy.xml

      -- artifact com.twitter#jsr166e;1.1.0!jsr166e.jar:

      /home/gopalkrishna/.ivy2/local/com.twitter/jsr166e/1.1.0/jars/jsr166e.jar

    ==== central: tried

      https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/twitter/jsr166e/1.1.0/jsr166e-1.1.0.pom

      -- artifact com.twitter#jsr166e;1.1.0!jsr166e.jar:

      https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/twitter/jsr166e/1.1.0/jsr166e-1.1.0.jar

    ==== spark-packages: tried

      http://dl.bintray.com/spark-packages/maven/com/twitter/jsr166e/1.1.0/jsr166e-1.1.0.pom

      -- artifact com.twitter#jsr166e;1.1.0!jsr166e.jar:

      http://dl.bintray.com/spark-packages/maven/com/twitter/jsr166e/1.1.0/jsr166e-1.1.0.jar

        module not found: org.scala-lang#scala-reflect;2.11.8

    ==== local-m2-cache: tried

      file:/home/gopalkrishna/.m2/repository/org/scala-lang/scala-reflect/2.11.8/scala-reflect-2.11.8.pom

      -- artifact org.scala-lang#scala-reflect;2.11.8!scala-reflect.jar:

      file:/home/gopalkrishna/.m2/repository/org/scala-lang/scala-reflect/2.11.8/scala-reflect-2.11.8.jar

    ==== local-ivy-cache: tried

      /home/gopalkrishna/.ivy2/local/org.scala-lang/scala-reflect/2.11.8/ivys/ivy.xml

      -- artifact org.scala-lang#scala-reflect;2.11.8!scala-reflect.jar:

      /home/gopalkrishna/.ivy2/local/org.scala-lang/scala-reflect/2.11.8/jars/scala-reflect.jar

    ==== central: tried

      https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-lang/scala-reflect/2.11.8/scala-reflect-2.11.8.pom

      -- artifact org.scala-lang#scala-reflect;2.11.8!scala-reflect.jar:

      https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-lang/scala-reflect/2.11.8/scala-reflect-2.11.8.jar

    ==== spark-packages: tried

      http://dl.bintray.com/spark-packages/maven/org/scala-lang/scala-reflect/2.11.8/scala-reflect-2.11.8.pom

      -- artifact org.scala-lang#scala-reflect;2.11.8!scala-reflect.jar:

      http://dl.bintray.com/spark-packages/maven/org/scala-lang/scala-reflect/2.11.8/scala-reflect-2.11.8.jar

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

        ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

        :: commons-beanutils#commons-beanutils;1.8.0: not found

        :: org.joda#joda-convert;1.2: not found

        :: joda-time#joda-time;2.3: not found

        :: io.netty#netty-all;4.0.33.Final: not found

        :: com.twitter#jsr166e;1.1.0: not found

        :: org.scala-lang#scala-reflect;2.11.8: not found

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::


:::: ERRORS
    Server access error at url https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/2.0.0-M2-s_2.11/spark-cassandra-connector-2.0.0-M2-s_2.11.pom (javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: protocol_version)

    Server access error at url https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/2.0.0-M2-s_2.11/spark-cassandra-connector-2.0.0-M2-s_2.11.jar (javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: protocol_version)

    Server access error at url https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/2.0.0-M2-s_2.11/spark-cassandra-connector-2.0.0-M2-s_2.11-sources.jar (javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: protocol_version)

    Server access error at url https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/2.0.0-M2-s_2.11/spark-cassandra-connector-2.0.0-M2-s_2.11-src.jar (javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: protocol_version)

    Server access error at url https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/2.0.0-M2-s_2.11/spark-cassandra-connector-2.0.0-M2-s_2.11-javadoc.jar (javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: protocol_version)

    Server access error at url https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils/1.8.0/commons-beanutils-1.8.0.pom (javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: protocol_version)

    Server access error at url https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils/1.8.0/commons-beanutils-1.8.0.jar (javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: protocol_version)

    Server access error at url https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/joda/joda-convert/1.2/joda-convert-1.2.pom (javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: protocol_version)

    Server access error at url https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/joda/joda-convert/1.2/joda-convert-1.2.jar (javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: protocol_version)

    Server access error at url https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/joda-time/joda-time/2.3/joda-time-2.3.pom (javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: protocol_version)

    Server access error at url https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/joda-time/joda-time/2.3/joda-time-2.3.jar (javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: protocol_version)

    Server access error at url https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/netty/netty-all/4.0.33.Final/netty-all-4.0.33.Final.pom (javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: protocol_version)

    Server access error at url https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/netty/netty-all/4.0.33.Final/netty-all-4.0.33.Final.jar (javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: protocol_version)

    Server access error at url https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/twitter/jsr166e/1.1.0/jsr166e-1.1.0.pom (javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: protocol_version)

    Server access error at url https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/twitter/jsr166e/1.1.0/jsr166e-1.1.0.jar (javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: protocol_version)

    Server access error at url https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-lang/scala-reflect/2.11.8/scala-reflect-2.11.8.pom (javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: protocol_version)

    Server access error at url https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-lang/scala-reflect/2.11.8/scala-reflect-2.11.8.jar (javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: protocol_version)


:: USE VERBOSE OR DEBUG MESSAGE LEVEL FOR MORE DETAILS
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: [unresolved dependency: commons-beanutils#commons-beanutils;1.8.0: not found, unresolved dependency: org.joda#joda-convert;1.2: not found, unresolved dependency: joda-time#joda-time;2.3: not found, unresolved dependency: io.netty#netty-all;4.0.33.Final: not found, unresolved dependency: com.twitter#jsr166e;1.1.0: not found, unresolved dependency: org.scala-lang#scala-reflect;2.11.8: not found]
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmitUtils$.resolveMavenCoordinates(SparkSubmit.scala:1078)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.prepareSubmitEnvironment(SparkSubmit.scala:296)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:160)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:126)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I strongly recommend you have a look at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Dumping code and output with no additional information is both unclear and not useful to others using the site. It helps if you start by explaining what you want, and detailing whatever research or other efforts you've tried.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [spark shell dependency exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51409064/spark-shell-dependency-exception)

Comment: it's a problem with Java TLS version - see linked answer

Answer (score 1):

But why are you using the version 2.0.0-M2? It's 3.5 years old, and is a preview of the new functionality, that isn't supposed to be used in production...

You need to use one of the latest versions, as pointed in the c[onnector documentation](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/0_quick_start.md), like:

```sh
bin/spark-shell --packages com.datastax.spark:spark-cassandra-connector_2.11:2.4.2
```

P.S. there are sometimes problems with Spark packages site, so you can try 2.4.0 instead of 2.4.2

Comment: Just tested both 2.4.2 & 2.4.0 - everything works out of box...

Comment: :: USE VERBOSE OR DEBUG MESSAGE LEVEL FOR MORE DETAILS
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: [unresolved dependency: com.datastax.spark#spark-cassandra-connector_2.11;2.4.2: not found]

Comment: Can you try with 2.4.0 - sometimes there are problems with Spark packages site