# How to resolve HTTP JVM: exception Received fatal alert: protocol_version

Tags: java, jvm, xpages, lotus-domino

My Xpages application is now throwing an error in the server console:

> HTTP JVM: exception Received fatal alert: protocol_version

The Xpages app is a few years old, but now, any updates to an existing Xpage breaks it with a browser message:

> HTTP Web Server: Item Not Found Exception

The xpages_exec log shows:

> com.ibm.xsp.page.PageNotFoundException: Could not create the page
>   /PageInfo.xsp because the class xsp.PageInfo could not be found. Please
>   check your spelling.

This may be 2 separate issues, I don't know.  How might I track down the cause?  Is it in the build or the run time?

The server shows the JVM version:

```
JVM: Java Virtual Machine initialized.
Java runtime version: 8.0.5.6 - pwa6480sr5fp6-20171124_02(SR5 FP6)
JVM version: JRE 1.8.0 Windows Server 2008 R2 amd64-64 20171122_371101 (JIT enabled, AOT enabled) OpenJ9 - 8e3c85d OMR - 713f08e IBM - c041ee8
```

How might I determine whether the Xpage build version will work with the run time?

The Java compiler workspace settings JDK compliance level is set to 1.5 with JRE 1.6 installed.

Comment: What version of Domino? You most likely will need the latest fix pack for 9.x to stay current or better upgrade to 11.x

Comment: Domino server version is 9.01FP10HF197

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16541627/javax-net-ssl-sslexception-received-fatal-alert-protocol-version#33494593

Comment: Try curl to see what protocol is used

Comment: How to set on the server: System.setProperty("https.protocols", "TLSv1")?

Comment: TLSv1 is deprecated by pretty much everyone. Too many security problems.

Comment: I am not sure what is throwing the protocol error, and I don't want to force TLSv1.  Would this have something to do with the server SSL certificate?

Comment: I have made a separate question re: the Xpage class not found.  The fatal protocol error may not be connected to that.