# Started getting errors building Grails 2 web app using Mail plugin

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

As of last Friday, an error is showing up when I do a 'grails war' with one of my Grails 2.2.5 applications:

```
:::: ERRORS
    SERVER ERROR: HTTPS Required url=http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/grails/plugins/mail/1.0.8-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml

    SERVER ERROR: HTTPS Required url=http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/grails/plugins/mail/1.0.8-SNAPSHOT/mail-1.0.8-SNAPSHOT.pom

    SERVER ERROR: HTTPS Required url=http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/grails/plugins/mail/1.0.8-SNAPSHOT/mail-1.0.8-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

The build seems to complete OK, but I'm concerned nonetheless. The error has just started happening, there have been no changes within my code, so I'm presuming it's to do with some change at a repo. In my BuildConfig.groovy, I have the plugins repo defined thus:

```
mavenRepo "http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins"
```

I wondered whether I might merely have to change this to https, but if I do so I get errors like the following: `Server access Error: Received fatal alert: protocol_version url=https://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins/org/grails/plugins/mail/1.0.8-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml` and the build fails because of unresolved dependencies.

Comment: Have you tried using https instead of http?

Comment: What Java version is this?

Comment: See https://blog.sonatype.com/central-repository-moving-to-https

Comment: @cfrick I doubt the Java version is relevant.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown yet OP stated they changed the URL and the error contains https.  So "protocol version" could mean old SSL/TLS in play

Comment: @cfricks It is possible.  More likely they are seeing the fact that maven central no longer accepts http.  Numerous folks are coming across that.  I think it started January 15.

Comment: As mentioned, merely changing the line in BuildConfig.groovy to `mavenRepo "https://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins"` did not fix the issue and caused a build failure. I'm certain the January 15 change is the key, but I'm not sure what I need to change to effect this.

Answer (score 1):

You are either using an old Java version or a misconfigured one.

See [javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: protocol_version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16541627/javax-net-ssl-sslexception-received-fatal-alert-protocol-version) for details how to deal with the `protocol_version` error.

And yes, you have to use `https` for the URL - repo.grails.org has moved over to https quite some time ago (citation needed)

Comment: I was able to resolve the protocol_version by adding `-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2` to the command which builds the war, but the original error messages still show up. Is it possible that this is something which needs to be changed within the plugin code itself?

Comment: You added it to the buildconf (or whats it called) and that fixed building the war? Or do you use JAVA_OTPS or GRAILS_OPTS (both from my memory, they might be called differently)

Comment: Oh and when you say "for this plugin" - have you bisected this problem?  Is it really _only_ for the mails plugin?  Or related to just snapshots?

Comment: I use a batch file to do the 'grails war' - basically what IntelliJ generates but with the memory tweaked a little. I put the `-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2` there, which ensures that Java (in my case jdk1.7.0_79) is using TLS 1.2. It prevented the fatal 'protocol_version' error and thus allowed the build to complete, although the original messages still displayed.

Comment: Yes, it's only the Mail plugin. There are other plugins installed, but only the Mail one causes the error message on build.

Comment: If you get this error inside IntelliJ, add the option there too.  But for your own sanity: get rid of this nearly five year old version of java and use the newest.  There are nowadays decent builds of the openjdk with all security stuff in it even for windows (at least zulu, don't know about adopt)

Comment: To move to Java 8 I would have to upgrade from Grails 2.2.5 to a later version, which is a reasonably large issue.

Comment: I am talking about 7 - only Oracle wont give you the updates for free any longer.

Comment: You mean a later version of OpenJDK 7?

Comment: Yes.  E.g. Azul provides community builds for windows from 6 and up.  I dont know about other openjdk "distributionns"

Comment: _I was able to resolve the protocol_version by adding -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2 to the command which builds the war, but the original error messages still show up_


worked for me on trying to run an downloaded app at Grails 2.5.6

Answer (score 0):

in this URL you can find this lib,
I use it: https://repo.grails.org/ui/native/plugins/org/grails/plugins/mail/1.0.8-SNAPSHOT/

I use with my local maven mavenLocal().