# Android Studio throwing "Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: protocol_version"

Tags: java, android, oracle, flutter, dart

I had formatted my system this morning only , after setting up all the path variables and completing all the setting still getting this error .

Did not had this issue when i last formated , need help.

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: protocol_version
at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.downloadInternal(Download.java:58)
at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.download(Download.java:44)
at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:61)
at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:48)
at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)
at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:128)
at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
```

Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: Checkout https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16541627/javax-net-ssl-sslexception-received-fatal-alert-protocol-version

Comment: I have seen that , but it did not help me. Also i am a completly new to this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue is resoleved.

firstly I updated my jdk from version 7 to 8
you can also download that form here https://www.techspot.com/downloads/5198-java-jre.html

then afterwards change the JAVA_HOME path in your system environment variables .

Afterwards i would suggest a cold shut-down and starting again this time Android studio will throw error saying license not accepted.

Open command prompt and run `flutter doctor`.

It will show you the exact issue and just accept all the licenses.

After that you are good to go.