# access remote neo4j with java

Tags: java, neo4j

I am trying to connect to a remote neo4j using java code. see this code:

```
        Driver driver = GraphDatabase.driver(url, AuthTokens.basic(username, password));
        Session session = driver.session();
        StatementResult result = session.run(query);

        ArrayList<Map<String, Object>> list = new ArrayList<>();
        while (result.hasNext()) {
            Record record = result.next();
            list.add(record.asMap());
        }
        session.close();
        driver.close();
```

I keep getting this with SSLException:

```
Apr 09, 2021 10:04:26 AM org.neo4j.driver.internal.logging.JULogger info
INFO: Direct driver instance 35238198 created for server address 89e9795b-eu-de.lb.appdomain.cloud:7687
Apr 09, 2021 10:04:33 AM org.neo4j.driver.internal.logging.JULogger info
INFO: Closing connection pool towards 89e9795b-eu-de.lb.appdomain.cloud:7687
Exception in thread "main" org.neo4j.driver.v1.exceptions.ServiceUnavailableException: Failed to establish connection with the server
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.util.Futures.blockingGet(Futures.java:123)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.DriverFactory.verifyConnectivity(DriverFactory.java:349)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.DriverFactory.newInstance(DriverFactory.java:95)
    at org.neo4j.driver.v1.GraphDatabase.driver(GraphDatabase.java:141)
    at org.neo4j.driver.v1.GraphDatabase.driver(GraphDatabase.java:124)
    at com.ibm.research.appmod.mf.Neo4JClient.executeQuery(Neo4JClient.java:46)
    at com.ibm.research.appmod.mf.Neo4JClient.executeQuery(Neo4JClient.java:80)
    at com.ibm.research.appmod.mf.Neo4JClient.executeQuery(Neo4JClient.java:76)
    at com.ibm.research.appmod.mf.Neo4JClient.main(Neo4JClient.java:109)
    Suppressed: org.neo4j.driver.internal.util.ErrorUtil$InternalExceptionCause
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.async.HandshakeHandler.transformError(HandshakeHandler.java:199)
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.async.HandshakeHandler.exceptionCaught(HandshakeHandler.java:96)
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:285)
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:264)
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:256)
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.exceptionCaught(SslHandler.java:1030)
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:285)
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.notifyHandlerException(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:850)
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:364)
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:286)
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1414)
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:945)
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:146)
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:645)
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:580)
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:497)
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:459)
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:886)
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:811)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: protocol_version
    at com.ibm.jsse2.k.a(k.java:19)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.aq.a(aq.java:604)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.aq.a(aq.java:192)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.aq.j(aq.java:161)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.aq.b(aq.java:303)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.aq.a(aq.java:316)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.aq.unwrap(aq.java:370)
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.unwrap(SSLEngine.java:11)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler$SslEngineType$3.unwrap(SslHandler.java:292)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1257)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1159)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1203)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:489)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:428)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:265)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:286)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1414)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:945)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:146)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:645)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:580)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:497)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:459)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:886)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:811)
```

I also tried this:

```
Config config = Config.builder()
                .withEncryption()
                .withTrustStrategy( Config.TrustStrategy.trustAllCertificates() )
                .build();
        Driver driver = GraphDatabase.driver(url, AuthTokens.basic(username, password),config);
        Session session = driver.session();
        StatementResult result = session.run(query);

        ArrayList<Map<String, Object>> list = new ArrayList<>();
        while (result.hasNext()) {
            Record record = result.next();
            list.add(record.asMap());
        }
        session.close();
        driver.close();
```

I have another app that is able to connect to the same neo4j. that is a springboot app, so that does not use direct queries like the avove code does .What do I need to do to make this work?

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/16541627/18157

Comment: What java version ? and what does the url look like ?

Comment: @aldrin I am using java8. 
url looks like this:
"bolt://<neo4j db host>:<bolt port>